# MS Access query to separate commas

Tags: html, ms-access

my project contains a MS Acces 2003  database, The table in the database contains a column called students name. The single column contains n numbers of names of student. For eg. John, Jim, Johny, Tom etc. They are dynamically added. Now what I want is, I want a complete list of all the names in the column. 
Like for eg. if the column is

**`Student_name`**

```
John, Jim, Johny, Tom, Jack
```

I want output as:

**`Student_name`**

```
John
Jim
Johny
Tom
Jack
```

The query must support MS Access. as i'm fetching the data in html file and I've attached that html file to MS Aacess database

Comment: You cannot split the values in Access SQL, you'll have to do it in code. Thus, the answer depends on the server-side technology you use to create the HTML output (php, asp, asp.net, ...).

Comment: from 1 rec to 5 recs ? .. or 1 rec to array ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `I've *attached* that html file to MS Access database`?

Comment: @Heinzi - So can you help me with the code to display such kind of output

Comment: @matzone - 1rec to 10 rec atleast

Comment: @Tim - Attach in the sense I've connected html file to Access database to store and retrieve the data.

Comment: @OmkarPawar: How do you "connect html file to Access database"?

Comment: @Heinzi - Using simple asp code

Comment: @OmkarPawar: Then the easiest solution might be to replace all ", " with "<br>". VBScript has a `Replace` function.

Comment: @OmkarPawar: I thought I just did. ;-) Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but MS Access doesn't provide functionality to run query in recursive mode as [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) does.  It's possible to use VBA macro to proceed through the collection of students to split comma separated values into set of records ;)

Let say, you have got table **Student** with fields:

- ID (numeric - integer),
- Students (string - char)

Sample data:

```
Id Students
1   John, Jim, Johny, Tom, Jack
2   Paula, Robert, Tim, Dorothy
5   Frank, Ramona, Giorgio, Teresa, Barbara
19  Isabell, Eve, Ewelina, Tadit
```

You need to create another table to store results of macro.

```
CREATE TABLE CTE1
(
    ID INT,
    OrigValue CHAR(255),
    SingleValue CHAR(255),
    Remainder CHAR(255)
);
```

To add macro, please do the following steps:

- go to Visual Basic code Pane
- insert new module
- copy below code and paste it into previously added module
- move the mouse cursor  into **ModifyMyData** procedure by clicking whenever inside its body
- run code (F5)

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

'need reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Object 2.8 Library

Sub ModifyMyData()
Dim sSQL As String
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim vArray As Variant
Dim i As Integer

'clear CTE table
sSQL = "DELETE * FROM CTE;"
CurrentDb.Execute sSQL

'initial query
sSQL = "INSERT INTO CTE (ID, OrigValue, SingleValue, Remainder)" & vbCr & _
    "SELECT ID, Students AS OrigValue, TRIM(LEFT(Students, InStr(1,Students,',')-1)) AS SingleValue, " & _
                "TRIM(RIGHT(Students,LEN(Students)-InStr(1,Students,','))) AS Remainder" & vbCr & _
    "FROM Student;"
CurrentDb.Execute sSQL

sSQL = "SELECT ID, OrigValue, SingleValue, Remainder" & vbCr & _
    "FROM CTE"
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open sSQL, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenStatic
With rst
    'fill rst object
    .MoveLast
    .MoveFirst
    'proccess through the
    Do While Not rst.EOF
        'Split Remainder into array
        vArray = Split(.Fields("Remainder"), ",")
        'add every single value
        For i = LBound(vArray) To UBound(vArray)
            sSQL = "INSERT INTO CTE (ID, OrigValue, SingleValue, Remainder)" & vbCr & _
                "VALUES(" & .Fields("ID") & ", '" & .Fields("OrigValue") & "','" & vArray(i) & "','" & GetRemainder(vArray, i + 1) & "');"
            CurrentDb.Execute sSQL
        Next
        .MoveNext
    Loop
    .Close
End With

Set rst = Nothing

MsgBox "Ready!"

DoCmd.OpenTable "CTE"

End Sub


Function GetRemainder(vList As Variant, startpos As Integer) As String
Dim i As Integer, sTmp As String
For i = startpos To UBound(vList)
    sTmp = sTmp & vList(i) & ","
Next

If Len(sTmp) > 0 Then sTmp = Left(sTmp, Len(sTmp) - 1)
GetRemainder = sTmp

End Function
```